# What to do when translation imported using Locale has an inappropriate translation?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I used Locale module to translate Drupal to my national language. But some words' translation is not appropriate. How can I change the translation of some words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to  Administer -> Site building -> Translate interface -> Search (d6) or Configuration -> Regional and language -> Translate interface -> Translate (d7). You will see a search box. Simply search and edit string you think should be edited.

[image]

Comment: If this is what worked for you, you can tick "accepted" mark. If not exactly, well, at least I'm glad you learnt something usable to you by this.

Comment: I'm new and I do not know directly rules. It's my fault. I ticked "accepted". Thanks.

Comment: @user19455 Not a fault. You are not *obligated* to accept answers. Acceptance means "from all answers this is the one I used and it worked for me" - only set it if that's what you want to say to future readers. Not all good answers needs to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix is to use the [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to override the translation of the specific words whose translation you disagree with.

A more community spirited solution would be to join the the translation team for your national language at https://localize.drupal.org/, and improve the translation by participating in the translation effort and discussions within the team about what is the *best* translation of a particular word or string.  If you get consensus about a change, the "official" translation of the word or string will be changed and you no longer need to override it.